# Link Arrows in pgfgantt for Long Periods of Time

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, links, pgfgantt, size

I am making a Gantt chart with pgfgantt. The arrowheads for dependencies between the bars do not show properly (e.g. pointing to left rather than right, for an input to another bar). My time-frame is eight months and I had to use "x unit" and "y unit" to contain the chart in a certain size.

The following is a minimal example that produces the same issue.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit chart = 0.65cm,
    y unit title = 0.75cm,
    x unit=0.5mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
  ]{2016-05-01}{2016-12-31}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname},\\
  \ganttbar{A}{2016-07-10}{2016-07-30} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{B}{2016-07-15}{2016-08-05} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar{C}{2016-08-05}{2016-08-25} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

For which the result is as the following image.

[image: pgfgantt Gantt chart with wrong arrowheads]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the `link bulge` factor with e.g. `\ganttlinkedbar[link bulge=4]{C}{2016-08-05}{2016-08-25}`. The default value is 0.4.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit chart = 0.65cm,
    y unit title = 0.75cm,
    x unit=0.5mm,
    time slot format=isodate,
  ]{2016-05-01}{2016-12-31}
  \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname},\\
  \ganttbar{A}{2016-07-10}{2016-07-30} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[link bulge=4]{B}{2016-07-15}{2016-08-05} \\
  \ganttlinkedbar[link bulge=4]{C}{2016-08-05}{2016-08-25} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```